# Javascript Passing Variable on Click

Tags: javascript

Im learning JS and working with passing variables between functions. I am trying to execute a function on click whilst passing a variable between functions. I can pass the variable by executing the function on page load, but cant do it on a click function.

```
function getData() {
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            //myFunction(myArr); 
            document.getElementById("start2").addEventListener("click", myFunction(myArr));
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

getData();


function myFunction(arr) {
    //  var arr = getData();
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<p>' + arr[i].id + '</p><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("answer-holder").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, since `addEventListener` expects a function as its second argument. But you do not provide a function. Instead you provide the result of evaluating `myFunction`, which is `undefined` (since `myFunction` does not return anything).

```
// when `addEventListener` is called, `myFunction` is also called immediately, 
// instead of first being called when the event is triggered 
document.getElementById("start2").addEventListener("click", myFunction(myArr));
```

You can fix the code by instead providing a function, that calls `myFunction` with your chosen argument.

```
document.getElementById("start2").addEventListener("click", function() {
   myFunction(myArr);
});
```

Comment: That is awesome, great answer and thanks for the explanation as that helps me to learn. Cheers

Comment: @insomniac22 No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling the function when trying to set the onClick listener:

```
document.getElementById("start2").addEventListener("click", myFunction(myArr));
```

As suggested by Thomas, you have to pass a function to addEventListener. However, I would suggest the newer lambda notation:

```
document.getElementById("start2").addEventListener("click", () => myFunction(myArr));
```